# Можно ли отследить обновление страницы по ссылке в заголовках?

Tags: php, http

Можно ли отследить дату последнего обновления/изменения страницы по ссылке в заголовках http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на сервере не запрещен метод HEAD:

[get_headers](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php)

Если запрещен:

```
define('HOSTNAME', 'ya.ru');
define('LM','Last-Modified');

$fd=fsockopen(HOSTNAME, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if($fd)
{
    $param = '';
    $lines = array();
    $hs = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $hs .= "Host: {HOSTNAME}\r\n";
    $hs .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite ($fd, $hs);
    $end = 0;
    while (!$end)
    {
        $param = fgets($fd, 1024);
        if(trim($param) == '') $end = 1;
        else $lines[] = $param;
    }
    fclose($fd);

    if(is_array($lines)&&count($lines))
        $last_modified = preg_grep("/^".LM."/", $lines);
    if(is_array($last_modified)&&count($last_modified))
        print_r($last_modified);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в результирующем массиве нет Last-Modified

Comment: Добавил вариант, если и в таком случаи не возвращает заголовок Last-Modified, значит сервер принудительно не посылает данный заголовок.

Comment: Какие есть еще варианты? Цель - определить, были ли изменения на странице, если были - запустить парсинг

Comment: Тут смотря какие изменения на странице отслеживаются. Если какой-то текст в конкретном блоке, то используйте функции по работе с деревом документа (DOMDocument), если нет, то можно по заголовку Content-Length длина контента.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял ваш вопрос...

Данный http-заголовок “Last-modified”возвращает дату последней модификации (обновления) запрашиваемой страницы сайта.

```
<?php header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s ")."GMT");?>
```

Comment: А как он формируется(обновляется)? Кто отслеживает изменения на странице?

Comment: Я имею ввиду заголовки ответа HTTP

Comment: Подробно можете почитать здесь:

http://site-on.net/optimization/7-last-modified

Comment: А если нужно отследить изменения на стороннем сайте? Т.е. определить, появилась ли на нем новая инфа?